# RadWindow not opening

Tags: c#, javascript, telerik, radwindow

RadWindow not open when i click over the button

My javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function OpenURL(URL) {
        var oWnd1 = radopen(URL, "Detalhamento do Contrato");
        oWnd1.set_height("600px");
        oWnd1.set_width("600px");
        oWnd1.center();
        oWnd1.set_modal(true);

    }
</script>
```

My C# code:

```
    protected void RadGrid_ItemCommand(object sender, GridCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName.Equals("Detalhes"))
        {
            String Parametros = "ContratoNumero=" + e.Item.OwnerTableView.DataKeyValues[e.Item.ItemIndex]["CONT_NUMERO"];
            Parametros += "&AditivoNumero=" + e.Item.OwnerTableView.DataKeyValues[e.Item.ItemIndex]["CONT_NUMADITIVO"];
            Parametros += "&ContratoTipo=" + e.Item.OwnerTableView.DataKeyValues[e.Item.ItemIndex]["CONT_TIPO"];
            Parametros += "&Exercicio=" + this.txtExercicio.Text;

            string URL = "ContratoDetalhamento.aspx?" + Parametros;

            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "relatorio", String.Format("OpenURL('{0}','{1}');", URL, DateTime.Now.Ticks), true);
        }
    }
```

Can someone help me ? 
Thanks for now

Comment: Have you checked whether the javascript function is called (I.E: `message("Arrives here")` ?

Comment: just refresh the page, but nothing happens

Comment: If you have `message("Arrives here")` at the beginning of the javascript function and it is now shown, your function is not being called.

Comment: You might find it useful to add `debugger;` to the start of your javascript function, this will allow you to step through the code and gives a bit more information that just alerting the user. I assume you've checked the obvious e.g. there is a RadWindowManager on the page.

Comment: When I'm wanting my server-side code to trigger javascript I use the following code: `Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(strScript.GetType(), String.Format("{0}_ScriptDescription", Me.ClientID), strScript, True)` where `strScript` is the javascript code to be run. I'm aware this isn't the best practice when using ScriptManagers but I find using other methods allows me to control where the code is triggered.

Comment: i have put the message("Arrives here") in the code, but nothing happens, the messege is not shown, only thing that happens is that refresh page.

Comment: I'm guessing it's a silly question, but do you have a `RadWindowManager` on the page?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing:

```
oWnd1.SetActive();
```

Answer (score 0):

1) look here on executing the script properly: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/radwindow-troubleshooting-javascript-from-server-side.html.

2) look here on the proper radopen() syntax: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/window-programming-opening.html.

Here is how I would do it:

```
function OpenURL(URL) {
    var oWnd1 = radopen(URL, "RadWindowName");//note, no spaces
    oWnd1.setSize(600, 600);//width, height
    oWnd1.set_modal(true);//making it modal will center it by default

}
```

Now, make sure you execute the code late enough:

```
string script = "function(f){openURL('url'); Sys.Application.remove_load(f);}Sys.Application.add_load(f);";
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.Page.GetType(), "someKey", script, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I want to share with you my solution to create RadWindow dialog in Javascript code only.

We need to implement 2 methods: one for initializing RadWindow dialog, and the last one for recieving the arguments returned after closing the RadWindow. You can do what you want in this second step (e.x postback,...)

Here is my code:

Initializing RadWindow dialog:

```
function openMyDialog(url, args) {
    var manageWindow = GetRadWindowManager();
    if (manageWindow) {
        var radWindow = manageWindow.open(url, "<your_dialog_name>");
        if (radWindow) {
            radWindow.set_initialBehaviors(Telerik.Web.UI.WindowBehaviors.None);
            radWindow.set_behaviors(Telerik.Web.UI.WindowBehaviors.Move + Telerik.Web.UI.WindowBehaviors.Close + Telerik.Web.UI.WindowBehaviors.Resize);
            radWindow.setActive(true);
            radWindow.SetModal(true);
            radWindow.center();
            radWindow.set_visibleStatusbar(false);
            radWindow.set_keepInScreenBounds(true);
            radWindow.set_minWidth(640);
            radWindow.set_minHeight(480);
            radWindow.setSize(640, 480);
            radWindow.set_destroyOnClose(true);
            radWindow.add_close(closeMyDialog);//after closing the RadWindow, closeMyDialog will be called
            radWindow.argument = args;//you can pass the value from parent page to RadWindow dialog as this line
        }
    }
}
```

Closing the RadWindow dialog:

```
function closeMoveProjectDialog(sender, args) {
    var objArgs = args.get_argument();
    //objArgs variable stored the values returned from the RadWindow
    //you can use it for your purpose
}
```

How to call this? You can put the open method into your expected method. In my side, I have a method as shown below and I will call the RadWindow as this way:

```
function ShowForeignKeyFrontEditSingle(param1, param2){
    var url = "ForeignKeyFrontEditSingle.aspx";
    var objArgs = new Array();
    objArgs[0] = param1;
    objArgs[1] = param2;

    openMyDialog(url, objArgs);
    return;
}
```

Of course, you have to declare a RadWindowManager control

```
function GetRadWindowManager() {
    return $find("<%=your_radwindow_manager_control.ClientID%>");
}
```